# Is there good idea to pass Hashmap Point as parameter in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am working on a csv read, the function is take a Hashmap, modify them and return filled data.

```
pub fn read_csv(
    maps: &mut HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>,
    ) -> Result<&HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>, Box<dyn Error>> {
 ....
}
```

This code seems very "ugly" ..

Comment: You can define a type alias as `type MyHashMap = HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>` and use `MyHashMap` in place of the original HashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a mutable reference then you're modifying the map in place, so I wouldn't bother returning it. You could return `Result<(), _>` with `()` signaling no return value on success.

```
pub fn read_csv(
    map: &mut HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    todo!();
}
```

Alternatively, you could take ownership of the map and then return it at the end. This would be appropriate if you want the map to be unusable when there's an error.

```
pub fn read_csv(
    map: HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>,
) -> Result<HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    todo!();
}
```

If you don't like the repetition you could, as [@Joe_Jingyu suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70342620/is-there-good-idea-to-pass-hashmap-point-as-parameter-in-rust/70342752#comment124345410_70342620), create a type alias.

```
pub type DateMap = HashMap<String, (NaiveDate, f64, NaiveDate, f64)>;

pub fn read_csv(map: DateMap) -> Result<DateMap, Box<dyn Error>> {
    todo!();
}
```

<sub>Nitpick: There's only one map so perhaps `map`, singular, would be a better variable name.</sub>